# Trusting all certificates in java Websocket client

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, java-websocket

First of all, I'm aware of the possible risks of trusting all certificates, however for some test purposes I have to implement this.

How can I force my client to trust all certificates? I'm implementing with `javax.websocket`

All I've done is simply connecting to ws like

```
WebSocketContainer client = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();

try {
    session = client.connectToServer(ClientImpl.class, URI.create(uri));
} catch (DeploymentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
I haven't found any solution, but I was able to use a self-signed certificate.

I describe all the steps:

1. Download the server certificate you want to connect, you can do it from your browser (in google chrome click right on the lock near the url of the page)
2. Create a keystore with the following command (Remember password you entered)

***keytool -import -alias localhost -file certificate_path -keystore your_new_keystore***

**I recommend you to use ClientManager instead of WebSocketContainer**. This allows you to override the hostname verification.

My code

```
System.getProperties().put("javax.net.debug", "all"); //usefull to understand problems

System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.KEY_STORE_FILE, your_new_keystore_path);

System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.TRUST_STORE_FILE, your_new_keystore_path);

System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD, the_password_you_entered);

System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD, the_password_you_enterede);   

ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();

SslEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = new SslEngineConfigurator(new SslContextConfigurator());

sslEngineConfigurator.setHostVerificationEnabled(false); //skip host verification

client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.SSL_ENGINE_CONFIGURATOR, sslEngineConfigurator);

client.connectToServer(you_class_with_ws_methods, your_ws_uri);
```

**you_class_with_ws_methods** can be the same you use with WebSocketContainer
Useful resources:

https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.10/user-guide.html#d0e1128      https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/securing_websocket_applications_on_glassfish